# error en kprototypes

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-requests

estoy intentando hacer un cluster en un dataframe con python y me genera el error.
kprototipos=kprototypes(n_cluster=3, verbose=2, max_inter=20)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

mi codigo es

```
introducir el código aquí


from re import VERBOSE
from kmodes import kprototypes
from pandas.core.arrays import categorical
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
import xlrd
import numpy as npd
import pandas as pd
from kmodes.kprototypes import KPrototypes
from xlrd import sheet

Entidades= pd.DataFrame(Entidades)

mark_array= Entidades.values



mark_array[:,6]=mark_array[:,6].astype(float)
mark_array[:,7]=mark_array[:,7].astype(float)
mark_array[:,8]=mark_array[:,8].astype(float)
mark_array[:,9]=mark_array[:,9].astype(float)
mark_array[:,10]=mark_array[:,10].astype(float)
mark_array[:,11]=mark_array[:,11].astype(float)


kprototipos=KPrototypes(n_cluster=3, verbose=2, max_inter=20)
kproto=kprototypes(n_clusters=3,verbose=2,max_inter=20)
clusters=kproto.fit_predict(mark_array,categorical=[0,1,2,3,4,5,12,13,14])
```

alguna idea?
muchas gracias

Comment: No debería de ser `KPrototypes(n_clusters=3,verbose=2,max_inter=20)`?

Comment: si, fue un error al copiar el codigo, pero me sigue dando el mismo error.